# Image don't load when i convert html to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have website in html and i have convert it in Wordpress Theme, after complete i see that images don't load, and i want to fix it.

You can see it [here](http://coo-sante.com)

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your website, you wrote `scr` instead `src`

For example:

`<img scr="http://coo-sante.com/wp-content/themes/coosante/logo/CooSanté.png" alt="logo">`

Change to:

`<img src="http://coo-sante.com/wp-content/themes/coosante/logo/CooSanté.png" alt="logo">`